# Give an example of a group G with a subgroup H and a prime p such that a Sylow p-subgroup of H is not a Sylow p-subgroup of G

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I don't understand why this is possible. If H is a subgroup of G then you know the order of H divides the order of G and same with P a subgroup of H so how could p not be a Sylow p-subgroup of G?

Comment: A Sylow $p$-subgroup has to be maximal. In your case, you might have $p \mid [G:H]$.

Comment: Do you know what a Sylow subgroup is? Refresh your memory.

Answer (score 4):

Let G be the cyclic group of order $p^{2}$. (p prime). It's it own sylow psubgroup. Consider the H subgroup of order $p$ in G.H us its own p sylow subgroup and is not a p sylow of G.

Comment: A simpler version of the same idea: Let $G$ be cyclic of order $p$ and let $H$ be the subgroup consisting of only the identity element.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G=S_3 \times C_3$, and $H=S_3 \times \{1\}$. Let $P=A_3 \times \{1\}$. Then $P \in Syl_3(H)$, but $P \notin Syl_3(G)$.